# Rails view variables not escaping spaces with %20, how do I force an escape?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, erb

I have a number of link_to's in my view that's in HAML.  One example is as follows:

```
= link_to "http://somedomain/submit?phase=2&url=#{request.fullpath}&title=#{page_title}", :target =>"_blank" do
```

As it turns out each time I attempt various escapes, I still get the "Use %20 in place of spaces" error from http://validator.w3.org.

**What is the proper way to escape a variable in this case?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have you tried using `URI::escape(string)`?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be what I want, however when I evoke this method on `page_title` I end up getting `undefined method `each_byte' for nil:NilClass`.  It seems as though, even though it does populate the data normally, that it's acting as nil when passed to that method...

Comment: hm does page_title have the possibility of including unicode characters at all?

Comment: I actually had an issue where the page title variable was not available at the point in the view share that I needed so I reworked it a bit and it is now working out well.  I also ended up setting page titles like this, which helped some as well to be more flexible: http://zetetic.net/blog/2010/05/18/pretty-page-title-in-rails-3/